# What is the best practice for arithmetic operations specially for package/class writing?

Tags: best-practices, package-writing, calculations, documentclass-writing

There are some possibilities to execute arithmetic operations inside a package or class.

### TeX

TeX supports `\advance`, `\multiply` or `\divide` to execute arithmetic operations. However the syntax is more or less "needs getting used to". Example:

```
\@tempdima=35pt
\advance\@tempdima by 10pt
\divide\@tempdima by 5
```

### eTeX

[eTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf) supports the commands `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr`. This simplify the example above as follows:

```
\@tempdima=\dimexpr (35pt+10pt)/5 \relax
```

### LaTeX3

[LaTeX3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) can be compared with eTeX.

```
\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { (35pt+10pt) / 5 }
```

---

### Packages

I know there are some packages which allow arithmetic operations, too. E.g. [calc](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) or [pgf](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Those packages can be compared with eTeX, too.

---

---

**However what is the recommended way of doing arithmetic operations inside a package/class? What are the benefits/drawbacks of the different approaches?**

Comment: You might want to specify a bit more detail, _e.g._ type [integers, dimensions, skips, (floating points)], expandability, _etc._

Comment: @JosephWright: I don't see any differences between the usage of `skip` nor `dimension` etc.?

Comment: For a package written in `expl3` using `expl3`'s possibilities seems natural. For a package written in LaTeX2e syntax I'd probably use `etoolbox`'s wrappers for the eTeX primitives. `etoolbox` has very handy 2e writing tools, anyway.

Comment: @cgnieder: A package using LaTeX ought use the functions of `expl3`. I think this is clear. As I wrote my package `mdframed` I used `dimexpr`. At comp.text.tex a guy told me that `dimexpr` is too slow and I should use TeX commands. So I switched. Now I want to switch back but is it recommended?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I don't really know about the efficiency of traditional TeX vs eTeX in terms of speed. To be frank: I never cared... ;) Someone else will know more. BTW: I believe `expl3` also wraps around the eTeX primitives.

Comment: Note that `expl3` is really using a very thin wrapper around the e-TeX primitives here (with the exception of `fp` operations, where there is no e-TeX support). As such, there will be very little in it performance wise between those two methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Time differences are not likely to really matter, the following test shows that tex primitives are fractionally faster than etex on my machine (and one would assume that latex3 or pgf or fp macros would be slower still).  However 16^6 is a lot of operations and this file does nothing else. In a real document TeX spends time typesetting or opening or writing files, so minor differences in computational speed are not likely to matter.

What matters more is that the computations are different: addition and multiplication are the same but etex uses rounding rather than truncating division (which is sort of OK, but different for lengths but is fairly useless for integer counts)
The test file produces

```
6.85713pt
6.85715pt
```

with the first value being from `\divide` and the second from etex `/`.

```
\makeatletter

\def\a{\@tempdima=38pt
\advance\@tempdima by 10pt
\divide\@tempdima by 7 }

\a\typeout{\the\@tempdima}

\def\b{\@tempdima=\dimexpr (38pt+10pt)/7 \relax}

\b\typeout{\the\@tempdima}

\def\c{\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a}
%\def\c{\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b}
\def\d{\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c}
\def\e{\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d}
\def\f{\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e\e}
\def\g{\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f}
\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g\g
\stop
```

Times:

tex

```
real    0m18.979s
user    0m18.408s
sys     0m0.124s
```

etex

```
real    0m20.351s
user    0m19.749s
sys     0m0.124s
```

Answer (score 8):

The biggest difference between traditional TeX computations and e-TeX extensions is that the latter allow for "on the fly" calculations, without assignments. This goes at the expense of speed, as `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr` and `\glueexpr` are slower than using registers.

However, in writing code, something like

```
\setlength\@tempdima        {\paperwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima      {-\textwidth}
\setlength\oddsidemargin    {.5\@tempdima}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin  {-1in}
\setlength\marginparwidth   {.5\@tempdima}
\addtolength\marginparwidth {-\marginparsep}
\addtolength\marginparwidth {-0.4in}
\addtolength\marginparwidth {-.4in}
```

(this is found in `size10.clo`) could be translated into the perhaps clearer

```
\setlength\oddsidemargin{%
  \dimexpr (\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2 - 1in \relax
}
\setlength\marginparwidth{%
  \dimexpr (\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2 - \marginparsep - 0.4in - 0.4in \relax}
```

(the double `-0.4in` can be understood by comparing the similar assignments when the `twoside` option is in force).

Due to the small differences in the way operations are performed (e-TeX division rounds, while traditional TeX division with registers truncates), it's not feasible now to change the standard classes into using the easier syntax, because older documents would be affected.

To the contrary, so long as a new package sticks to one syntax, I'd say that a clearer method is to be preferred: the code is less obscure and more easily maintained.

In LaTeX3 parlance, the two assignments would become

```
\dim_set:Nn \oddsidemargin  { (\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2 - 1in }
\dim_set:Nn \marginparwidth { (\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2 - \marginparsep - 0.4in - 0.4in }
```

which is even clearer.