# Floating point and fixed point arithmetic in LaTeX3: Where documented? Safe to use?

Tags: calculations, latex3

Since about twenty years, I use a private fixed point arithmetic package which I would like to replace by something newer and better. There is the equally old (but good) `fp` package, but LaTeX3 is rising and I found a many questions and answers where LaTeX3 was recommended:

- [Floating point calculations in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/floating-point-calculations-in-latex)
- [What is the best practice for arithmetic operations specially for package/class writing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/what-is-the-best-practice-for-arithmetic-operations-specially-for-package-class)
- [How to format expl3 floating point number using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119087/how-to-format-expl3-floating-point-number-using-siunitx)
- http://www.texdev.net/category/latex3/
- [Replacing dots with comma in `fp` result](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141963/replacing-dots-with-comma-in-fp-result/142004#142004)

Unfortunately, I was not able to find the documentation of the arithmetic functions of LaTeX3. One of the above linked texts mentions a `l3fp` package which I could not find. I scanned through the `expl3` documentation, but I also could not find the arithmetic functions documented. Googling gives a lot of examples, but where is the documentation?

If there is one, please, let me know.

Or is it not *officially* documented, because it's currently not seen as stable? The `xparse` package e.g. is declared stable and is documented. Is it too early for the arithmetic functions?

Comment: `texdoc l3fp` or `texdoc interface3` which both give the same document.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. `texdoc l3fp` finds nothing (on my system which was updated recently), but `interface3.pdf` exists. This seems to be the documentation I was looking for. Thank you! Is it obvious to look for `interface3.pdf`? Then I would delete my question...

Comment: I don't know, I think I'm aware of it because it has been mentioned here on the site, or in chat. I can't really comment on stability, so I think you could leave it for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `l3fp` is part of the 'code level' `expl3` implementation, the documentation is included in `interface3`: a programmers' reference. As it implements the same arithmetic operations as are (commonly) provided by other languages, the documentation for the individual operations is not that detailed.

In terms of 'stability', I'd say that  [How "safe" is it to use LaTeX3 (l3packages, l3kernel)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145335/how-safe-is-it-to-use-latex3-l3packages-l3kernel) covers much of this. The floating point code is part of the `l3kernel` package, which the team aim to keep 'broadly stable'. There seems little likelihood of removal of anything from `l3fp` (all relatively new and with no issues known in terms of interfaces). As such, it's no more risky than any other code or package, and probably at least as 'safe' as anything else where development is ongoing. (I note `fp` has not changed for many years, so it's entirely stable in that sense.)

Comment: Thank you! `interface3` is the documentation I was looking for. Somehow it slipped away from me... it's even located in the same directory as `expl3`. Your words about stability are reassuring. Actually, I was reading a little bit in your excellent `siunitx` documentation today, when this question about arithmetics came up to me... One last point: Are there plans for a fixed point arithmetic besides the more common floating point arithmetic? Maybe, it's too special for the kernel, but it would be useful for e.g. financial calculations.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm No specific plans on fixed point arithmetic. For most purposes, floating calcs using IEEE854 are sufficient. We do have some 'big integer' code, but at present that's not in the kernel. (I'd quite like some parts of that for `siunitx`!)

Comment: What do you mean by that last parenthetical comment?  I know that new stuff has been added to the `fp` library recently (inverse tan springs to mind).

Comment: @AndrewStacey I was referring to the 'big integers' point I'd made. 'Big integers' would be handy for some internals in `siunitx`, and also cover the fixed-point question (just a question of a power-of-ten shift for financial calculations, for example).